# Unable to install drivers for NodeMCU in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I'm trying to start with NodeMCU on my linux machine. While installing the drivers for NodeMCU, [CH341SER_LINUX](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit/tree/master/Drivers), the Makefile build gives the following error:

```
root@ashtava:~/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX (1)/CH341SER_LINUX# make -f Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/build  M=/home/ashtava/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX (1)/CH341SER_LINUX  
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

Below Error in your command output, states what is wrong here :

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

And you are getting this error because of the space and parentheses in the file name. So, when shell encounters space in your command, it treats it as end of filename :

**`/home/ashtava/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX`**

And rest part :

**`(1)/CH341SER_LINUX`**

is treated as another argument to command `make`, but before that shell encounters a parentheses to which it freaks out.

#### The Solution

You can do one of the following or perhaps try all of them :

- [Using the quotes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html) single or double around your filename like :

  `M='/home/ashtava/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX (1)/CH341SER_LINUX'`

  OR

  `M="/home/ashtava/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX (1)/CH341SER_LINUX"`
- Using Escape character **`\`** to tell shell to treat special characters ( here parentheses **( )** and space  ) as plain characters like :

  `M=/home/ashtava/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX\ \(1\)/CH341SER_LINUX`

---

Here is a [good read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053121/7975442) on what characters need to escaped when using Bash ?.

Feel free to add-in more details.